# bash mysql insert single qoute

Tags: mysql, bash, insert, quote

I sometimes have $title return with quote within it. Is there any proper way to

1. Keep it while inserting or
2. Just simply remove it so it doesn't kick back errors?

   echo "INSERT INTO $SQL_DATABASE.$SQL_TABLE SET $SQL_FILENAME_FIELD='$OUTPUTFILENAME', title='$title', url='$OUTPUTFILENAME', cover='$OUTPUTFILENAME.jpg', server='s2', dateadd=now(), lastplayed=now()-interval 2 day, record='1000', channel='2', downloaded='1';" \
   | mysql -h$SQL_HOST -u$SQL_USERNAME -p$SQL_PASSWORD $SQL_DATABASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tr command is used here to delete the ' character from title.

```
 title=$(echo $title | tr -d "'")
```

To output only alphanumeric chars, the -cd options will delete all characters which are not alphanumeric.

```
 title=$(echo $title | tr -cd "[:alnum:]")
```

Comment: can we make this remove all weird characters as well? perhaps only keep letters and numbers only?

Answer (score 2):

To keep the quotes you need to escape them, instead of using $title use this instead:

```
${title//\'/\'\'}
```

This will transform
`It's a beautiful day` into `It''s a beautiful day`.

Here is the full command line:

```
echo "INSERT INTO $SQL_DATABASE.$SQL_TABLE SET $SQL_FILENAME_FIELD='$OUTPUTFILENAME', title='"${title//\'/\'\'}"', url='$OUTPUTFILENAME', cover='$OUTPUTFILENAME.jpg', server='s2', dateadd=now(), lastplayed=now()-interval 2 day, record='1000', channel='2', downloaded='1';"
```

Comment: i honestly would not know how to use this - even thought I would love to store quotes inside the db so when I pull it out, it looks nicer...

Comment: @thevoipman : Brace expansion is powerfull stuff, you should learn it.